# Merge results of duplicate fields

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JSON file which looks like the following:

```
{
    "name1": 
    {
        "fields": 
        {
            "Name": 
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            "Email":
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            "Password":
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            "role":
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        }
    },
    "name2":
    {
        "fields": 
        {
            "url":
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        }
    },
    "name1":
    {
        "fields": 
        {                        
            "Address":
            {
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to iterate through it and if there is a name which already exists I want to merge the fields; here is my code:

```
var DBSchema = [];
async.each(Object.keys(config), function(key) {
    var currentObject = config[key];
    var DBSchemaTemp = [];
    for (var field in currentObject.fields) {
        if (currentObject.fields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            DBSchemaTemp[field] = {AttributeName: field,
                AttributeType: currentObject.fields[field].type
            }
        }
    }
    var arrayInSchema = DBSchema[key];

    if (typeof arrayInSchema === 'undefined') {
        DBSchema[key] = [];
        DBSchema[key].push(DBSchemaTemp);
    } else {
        DBSchema[key].concat(DBSchemaTemp);
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

for (variable in DBSchema) {
    console.log(variable);
    console.log(DBSchema[variable]);
}
```

My desired output is:

```
{ 
    name1: [ Name: { AttributeName: 'Name', AttributeType: 'STRING' },
 Email: { AttributeName: 'Email', AttributeType: 'STRING' },
 Password: { AttributeName: 'Password', AttributeType: 'STRING' },
 role: { AttributeName: 'role', AttributeType: 'STRING' }   Address: { AttributeName: 'Address', AttributeType: 'STRING' } ] 
 name2:  [ url: { AttributeName: 'url', AttributeType: 'STRING' } ]  
}
```

but my code returns:

```
 { name1: [ [   Address: { AttributeName: 'Address', AttributeType:  'STRING' } ] ] name2: [ [ url: { AttributeName: 'url', AttributeType:  'STRING' } ] ] }
```

Please note; for some reason it is adding double [[]] as well!

Comment: You are missing a comma before the second `"name1":`

Comment: @user3421904: What was the solution? You should consider posting it below (and marking it as accepted) for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Maybe my previous statement was confusing! I dont know the solution yet! I just fixed a typo in json file, but still I have the same problem with my code! I'm trying to figure out the solution

Comment: I believe the problem is DBSchema[key].concat(DBSchemaTemp); when I try to concat the index is different (If you look at the added [[]] you see the index should be changed!) But I dont know how ...